# Disallow setting a particular value in Swift

Tags: swift, swift4

I want to 'disallow' setting a value such as 0 to a var (float or int) to make sure it can be a proper divisor. What is the correct way to achieve this in Swift? One way I can think of is to put fatalError() in didSet method, but I guess Swift may have better ways to deal with it.

Answer (score 2):

You have a few options, but I think it boils down to your preference and how your variable is going to be used.

`fatalError()` would be appropriate if setting it to `0` would be a programmer error, it should be caught by testing your app. Personally, I would avoid this.

You could also use `didSet` to modify the value to a non-zero value, like `1`.

Another option would be to use a function to set the value, and make that function throw an error when passing `0`, that way the code that sets the value can respond to that and alert the user.

This is how the last option, which is what I would do, would be implemented:

```
enum InputError: Error {
  case divisorCantBeZero
}

private var _divisor: CGFloat = 1
var divisor: CGFloat {
  return _divisor
}

func setDivisor(_ newValue: CGFloat) throws {
  guard newValue != 0 else {
    throw InputError.divisorCantBeZero
  }
  _divisor = newValue
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest looking at `precondition` and/or `assert` for this.

Depending on the seriousness of the problem when setting 0 then you can choose one or the other.